# ARIMAX on Multiple Time Series with same Timestamp

Tags: python, arima, forecast

I am new to machine learning using python. 
I have time series data having multiple IDs (say 100) with same time stamp of 12 months (11 months - Train data , 1 month - Test data). I tried **ARIMAX** (Python) on single ID (ACF , PACF, ADF test to get order), later calculate MAE, RMSE for that ID (worked well).
Now I want to forecast all 100 IDs in test duration (last 1 month) and calculate average MAE and RMSE on each day and plot a distribution for 30 days.
Is there an function that forecast all IDs.